# проверка выбора вариации woocommerce

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы при нажатии "добавить в корзину" было сообщение или визуальный указатель на то что нужно выбрать атрибуты (например размер майки и цвет)

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ - это добавить тегу атрибут required. Он выделяет поля обязательные к заполнению перед отправкой формы. К нему также можно добавить стилевые правила.
Например:

```
<label for="mark">Имя</label>
<input id="mark" type="text" required>
```

CSS:

```
input:required {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000; /* Появление красной рамки если поле не заполнено */
}
```